# Modify sh.vim to accept (@)_ as part of a variable name for Bash highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-sh

I have Bash file in which I have constructs that include `(@)_` as part of the variable name.  For example:

```
(@)_VariableName
${(@)_VariableName[@]}
${#(@)_VariableName[@]}
${!(@)_VariableName[@]}
```

The Bash files are pre-processed and the literal string `(@)_` is replaced with characters so that the final result is valid Bash. The sequence `(@)_`, if present, will always be at the beginning of a variable name.

I'd like to modify the `sh.vim` syntax file so that variable names are considered to be valid in identifier highlighting and not shown with `shDerefWordError` highlighting.  I've tried modifying:

```
syn match shDerefVar contained "{\@<=!\k\+" nextgroup=@shDerefVarList
```

to:

```
syn match shDerefVar contained "{\@<=\((@)_\)\?!\k\+" nextgroup=@shDerefVarList
```

but this has not worked.

Note that this allowance might reasonably be made conditional to a variable such as `b:is_eggsh`.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. The problem is that you took the syntax definition for Bash's special `${!varname}`, and that doesn't match.

I would also define a separate syntax group, used exclusively for your placeholder variables. The sh.vim syntax script is extensive via syntax clusters, that's how you install it as an additional dereference:

```
syn match shDerefPlaceholder contained "{\@<=[!#]\?(@)_\k\+" nextgroup=@shDerefVarList
syn cluster shDerefList add=shDerefPlaceholder
```

#### Alternative

Integrating with an existing syntax can be messy... especially with an advanced one like shell (which supports several sub-modes). An alternative would be using `:match Preproc /(@)_[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/`; this always applies over existing syntax highlighting. Only complication: this is window-local, so you'd need some `:autocmds` to install it, like this:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead * if &syntax == 'sh' | match Preproc /(@)_[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/ | endif
```

Comment: Hi Ingo... that almost does it.  I still see error highlighting in the case of `${#(@)_VariableName[@]}` or `${!(@)_VariableName[@]}`. Would you mind updating your answer to address these as well?  Many thanks!!

Comment: Great! Supporting those should be a matter of inserting `[!#]\?` at the right place; see my edit.

Comment: That's what I thought, too.  But, they're still showing up with the error highlighting.  Is it possible that escaping is needed?

Comment: I previously didn't say that the code was working for the other cases.  Almost there!  Is it possible that the `syn match shDerefSpecial` is taking priority or something like that?

Comment: I found one more item: when the variable is being defined, it isn't being dereferenced.  For example, `local (@)_VariableName`. This isn't being highlighted.  Please know that I very much appreciate your help on this!

Comment: All of that seems to depend on the shell type. I have `b:is_posix` and `b:is_sh`, and everything highlights fine. But if I `:let b:is_bash` and reload, I see the error highlighting in definitions and with `${#` and `${!`.

Comment: I tried updating my vim to current.  My sh.vim is now version 162 (Aug 31, 2016) for vim 8.0.42. This didn't help resolve the issue for the `${#` and `${!` variables. Can you suggest what I might need to do?  Also, for variable definitions such as `local (@)_VariableName=value`, it seems that the `shCmdParenRegion` rule is taking precedence.  Any ideas on how to resolve these issues? Thanks.

Comment: is there a way just to have `(@)_[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` (and similarly with the `${...}` variants override _all_ other syntax rules?

Comment: Yeah, integrating with an existing syntax can be messy... especially with an advanced one like shell (which supports several sub-modes). An alternative would be using `:match Preproc /(@)_[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/`; this always applies _over_ existing syntax highlighting. Only complication: this is window-local, so you'd need some `:autocmd`s to install it.

Comment: Great!  I've added the following rule and it is satisfactory! `au BufNewFile,BufRead * if &syntax == 'sh' | match shEggsh /(@)_[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/ | endif`

Comment: `hlsearch` with the above didn't show my shEggsh highlighting on top of the hlsearch highlighting, so I've done the following instead to specify a lower priority (-1): `au BufNewFile,BufRead * if &syntax == 'sh' | call matchadd('shEggsh','(@)_[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*',-1) | endif`. I hope this helps someone!

Comment: `autocmd`s not necessary: use `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sh.vim`